# How to set multiple property values with same name and counter value using reflection?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a class with a separate field for `Email`. Then I have fields as `Email1`, `Email2`, ..., `Email9`

I receive values in the form of xml like this

```
<user Email="abc@gmail.com">
   <Contact Name="test1" Email="a1@qqq.com"/>
   <Contact Name="test2" Email="a2@qqq.com"/>
</user>
```

There can be no contact or up to nine contacts in a single user. How can I assign these values to my properties using linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better design you should have an entity `Contact` in addition to your class `User`, so each user can have `List<Contact>` as you described like this:

```
public class User
{
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then the linq query used to populate the class might be as follows:

```
XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(@"..\Users.xml");
var users = from x in xmlDoc.Elements()
            select new User
            {                
               Email = (string) x.Attribute("Email"),
               Contacts = new List<Contact>(
                          from c in x.Elements()
                          select new Contact
                          {
                              Name = (string) c.Attribute("Name"),
                              Email = (string) c.Attribute("Email")
                          }
               )
            };
```